# Openshift: App deleted after one month of inactivity

Tags: openshift

I have a free openshift account and I created an app in July. After a month of inactivity i tried to use the app and:
-The web browser cannot resolve the url
-If I log in openshift I cannot see the app (the account is the same)

I'm not interested in finding the code because I have it on my pc, but I spent a lot of time in filling the database, is there anyway to restore it? After that, can someone explain me why my app has been deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenShift Online (Next Gen) environment is only in developer preview mode at this time. The FAQ on the main page at:

- https://www.openshift.com/devpreview/

where you would have passed through when signing up states:

- HOW LONG WILL I HAVE ACCESS TO THE ENVIRONMENT?

  > You will have access to the OpenShift Online (Next Gen) Developer Preview environment for 30 days, at which point your account will expire.
- WHAT HAPPENS WHEN MY ACCOUNT EXPIRES?

  > Your account, applications, and data will be permanently deleted to free up resources for other users when your account expires. This means that you will no longer be able to log in to the web console, authenticate using the OpenShift CLI tools, or access your applications and related data.
- CAN I CREATE A NEW ACCOUNT AFTER MY ACCOUNT EXPIRES?

  > If you're interested in trying the OpenShift Online (Next Gen) Developer Preview again, just complete the registration form after your account expires and we will provision a fresh set of resources for you as soon as they become available.

Comment: thank you for clearing things up. Can you suggest me another platform for hosting python - django applications for free?